# Does tmux need to be detached to survive ssh failure?

Tags: ssh, tmux

When people talk about tmux's ability to survive ssh failure, they usually say: "ssh into your remote box, start a tmux session, run your process, then detach the tmux session. If ssh drops your process will still be alive when you ssh in again".

To clarify: if the ssh connection drops while the tmux session is active (not detached), is the process killed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The TMUX session will survive if your ssh session fails.

Just reconnect to the server and attach to the tmux session with

```
List tmux sessions: tmux ls
Attach to tmux session: tmux a
Attach to named session: tmux a -t myname
```

Here is a good cheat sheet: https://gist.github.com/henrik/1967800